# Memory Leak Occurs While Implementing FusedLocationProvider

Tags: android, memory-leaks, gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am facing a memory leak problem during GPS location implementation. I have used basic implementation process of FusedLocationProvider to get last location.
But according to the backtrace, it is showing memory leak due to this implementation.
Is any one face same type of memory leak issue while implementing FusedLocationProvider API? And what should I follow to avoid memory leak here?
I am sharing my dumpstate log, memory trace log, and the code snippet for better understanding of the problem.
**Here is the log link:**
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bzeACMj6erp2up9pgmueawixi8JVhICw?usp=sharing

Any kind of suggestion would be helpful.

**Tested the issue on below device:**

RAM: 2GB
Software Version: T295XXU4BUD3

[Samsung](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm1H8.jpg)

Here is the Code Snippet:

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**Initialization**

```
 private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
 private LocationRequest locationRequest;
 private LocationCallback locationCallback;
 private boolean isGPS = false;
 private boolean skipGPS;
 private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000, FASTEST_INTERVAL = 3000;
```

**onCreate**

```
skipGPS = false;
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());

        new GpsUtils(HouseholdActivity.this).turnGPSOn(new GpsUtils.onGpsListener() {
            @Override
            public void gpsStatus(boolean isGPSEnable) {
                // turn on GPS
                isGPS = isGPSEnable;
            }
        });
        //prepareGpsAccess(); //causing memory leak..
}
```

**Method Implementation:**

```
public void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(HouseholdActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(HouseholdActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(HouseholdActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    AppConstants.LOCATION_REQUEST);

        } else {
            if (mFusedLocationClient != null) {
                mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(HouseholdActivity.this, location -> {
                    if (location != null) {
                        
                        Log.e(TAG, "Location: " + location.getLatitude());
            Log.e(TAG, "Location: " + location.getLongitude());

                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Location: callback triggered...");
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }


  @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        Log.e(TAG, "Permission missing... result");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1000: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(HouseholdActivity.this, location -> {
                        if (location != null) {
                                household.setLat(location.getLatitude());
                                household.setLon(location.getLongitude());
                            
                        } else {
                            //mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == AppConstants.GPS_REQUEST) {
                isGPS = true; // flag maintain before get location
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Google has recently resolved this memory leak issue in their latest play-services-location:20.0.0 release. [Release Note](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_07_2022).

So update your lib version to 20.0.0 and it will solve the problem, it did for me.

To know more about the history of this memory leak, check [this](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/while-in-use-location/issues/7) and [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37126862?pli=1).